# Require path errors thrown

Tags: ruby, require

I wrote a ruby class that I want to use in other applications that I have. I put it in the same directory c:\apps that I have my other applications in. When I require my class it says that:

```
`require': no such file to load --
```

Even though the file is in the same directory as the application I am running. I am simply doing a :

```
require 'fileformat'
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I did /apps/fileformat and it worked